# How to login on Flutter Web Application by pressing the Enter-Key

Tags: flutter, keyboard-shortcuts, flutter-web, keyboard-events

I'm currently working on a login-page for a flutter web application. For the authentication I'm using Firestore, the authentication method is signing in with email and password.
Therefore I created text fields for email and password and a submit button. The login itself works fine, the issue is, I always have to click on the submit button to login. As I'm building a web application, I'd like to be able to just hit the Enter key after typing my email and password, but I can't get this to work and I'm already quite frustrated because I think this should be an easy no-brainer as it is such normal and expected behaviour, at least in my oppinion...

That said, I'm pretty new to flutter and to programming in general, so please use low-level explanations for me to be able to understand you. ;-)

After unsuccessfully trying to use KeyboardListener and RawKeyboardListener, I think the best way to go should be using CallbackShortcuts, but when I press the Enter key after typing the email and password, nothing seems to happen. On the other hand, if I don't provide an email, I get the "Email is badly formatted"-Error-Massage, so obviously something happens, but what? I'm lost. Here is the relevant code:

```
class LoginPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const LoginPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<LoginPage> createState() => _LoginPageState();
}

class _LoginPageState extends State<LoginPage> {
  String? errorMessage = '';
  bool isLogin = true;

  final TextEditingController _controllerEmail = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController _controllerPassword = TextEditingController();

  Future<void> signInWithEmailAndPassword() async {
    try {
      await Auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(
          email: _controllerEmail.text, password: _controllerPassword.text);
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      setState(() {
        errorMessage = e.message;
      });
    }
  }

  Widget _emailField() {
    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
      width: 400,
      height: 50,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: textLight,
          border: Border.all(
            color: textDark,
          ),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5))),
      child: TextField(
        controller: _controllerEmail,
        decoration: const InputDecoration(
          hintText: "Email",
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _passwordField() {
    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 5.0),
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
      width: 400,
      height: 50,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: textLight,
          border: Border.all(
            color: textDark,
          ),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5))),
      child: TextField(
        controller: _controllerPassword,
        decoration: const InputDecoration(hintText: "Passwort"),
        obscureText: true,
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _errorMessage() {
    return Text(
      errorMessage == '' ? '' : "Error: $errorMessage",
      style: TextStyle(color: textError),
    );
  }

  Widget _submitButton() {
    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
      width: 150,
      height: 50,
      child: ElevatedButton(
        style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
          backgroundColor: textLight,
        ),
        onPressed: signInWithEmailAndPassword,
        child: Text(
          'Anmelden',
          style: TextStyle(
            color: textDark,
            fontSize: 20,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CallbackShortcuts(
      bindings: {
        const SingleActivator(LogicalKeyboardKey.enter):
            signInWithEmailAndPassword,
      },
      child: Focus(
        autofocus: true,
        child: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            backgroundColor: primaryGreen,
            centerTitle: true,
            title: _title(),
            leading: Container(
              margin: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: const Image(
                image: AssetImage('assets/images/BAAppLogo.png'),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          body: Container(
            height: double.infinity,
            width: double.infinity,
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
            decoration: gradientDecoration,
            child: Container(
              decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                image: DecorationImage(
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  image: AssetImage('assets/images/background_green_admin.png'),
                  fit: BoxFit.contain,
                ),
              ),
              child: Center(
                child: SingleChildScrollView(
                  child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      _screenText(),
                      _emailField(),
                      _passwordField(),
                      _errorMessage(),
                      _submitButton(),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is very simple,
in your textfield just use property **onSubmitted**
there put your logic to redirect when enter is pressed.

Comment: in your password field use it like onSubmitted:(){ /*WRITE HERE THE LOGIC*/}